# Hive - get latest record with no blank column

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I have 2 tables:
Table 1:

```
emp_id emp_log_id timestamp
1      234       04 Oct 2019 23:10
1                05 Oct 2019 23:10
2      335       04 Oct 2019 23:10
2                03 Oct 2019 23:10
3                04 Oct 2019 23:10
4      324       04 Oct 2019 23:10
```

> My expected output is:

```
emp_id emp_log_id timestamp
1 234 04 Oct 2019 23:10
2 335 04 Oct 2019 23:10
3  04 Oct 2019 23:10
4 324 04 Oct 2019 23:10
```

1. If the latest record has emp_log_id, then take that(sample emp_id: 2
2. If the latest record doesn't have emp_log_id then go back to the previously updated record(sample emp_id: 1)

**How to write hive query for this**.

Another table has data like:
Table 2:

```
emp_id emp_log_id
    1 234
    1  05
    2 335
    2  03
    3  04
    4 324
```

**How to implement the same requirement in this table 2.**

Please help.

Comment: It isn't very clear what you want. Can you edit your post with more details

Comment: According to your description, the answer from @Gordon Linoff should be better. The accepted answer does not guarantee that `emp_log_id` and `timestamp` come from the same record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using aggregation function `max()` will do it.

```
select emp_id, max(emp_log_id) as emp_log_id, timestamp 
from table1
group by emp_id, timestamp
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by emp_id
                                order by (emp_log_id is not null) desc, timestamp desc
                               ) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1
```